# Kafka listener container with multiple reply templates

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka listener with two registered handlers, each listening for messages on the same topic but with different schema types. Listeners make use of forwarding results to another topic with `@SendTo` annotation and EOS is enabled by `@Transactional`.

```java
@KafkaListener(
        groupId = "groupId",
        clientIdPrefix = "kafka-async-api-commands-listener",
        topics = "cmd-topic",
        containerFactory = "kafkaAsyncApiCommandsListenerContainerFactory",
        errorHandler = "kafkaAsyncApiErrorHandler"
)
public class KafkaAsyncApiCommandsListener {

    @KafkaHandler
    @Transactional
    @SendTo("resp-topic")
    Message<FooResponse> Foo(FooCommand command) {
        FooResponse response = new FooResponse(command);
        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(response)
                .build();
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    @Transactional
    @SendTo("resp-topic")
    Message<BarResponse> calculateBar(BarCommand command) {
        BarResponse response = new BarResponse(command);
        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(response)
                .build();
    }
}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-send-to):

> In order to support @SendTo, the listener container factory must be provided with a KafkaTemplate (in its replyTemplate property), which is used to send the reply.

KafkaTemplate is a parametrized type and requires providing both key and value of messages it is going to be producing. I have a problem coming up with a template supporting both `FooResponse` and `BarResponse` as a message type. And it seems to be a must, as container factory accepts only one template.

Since both templates are desired to share the entire configuration foundation (properties, error handler) I could instantiate a template of type `KafkaTemplate<UUID, Object>` capable of producing messages with both `FooResponse` and `BarResponse` serialized bodies and inject it into the container factory:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaAsyncApiProducerTemplatesConfig {

    private final String bootstrapServers;

    public KafkaAsyncApiProducerTemplatesConfig(@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers) {
        this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
    }

    @Bean("asyncApiResponseTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<UUID, Object> asyncApiResponseKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaAsyncApiProducerFactory());
    }

    private ProducerFactory<UUID, Object> kafkaAsyncApiProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, UUIDSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class KafkaAsyncApiCommandsListenerContainerFactory extends ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<UUID, CalculateCustomerBalanceCommand> {

    private final String bootstrapServers;
    private final KafkaTemplate<UUID, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    public KafkaAsyncApiCommandsListenerContainerFactory(
            @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers,
            @Qualifier("asyncApiResponseTemplate") KafkaTemplate<UUID, Object> kafkaTemplate
    ) {
        super();
        this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig()));
        this.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000, 3)));
        this.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
            put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
            put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, UUIDDeserializer.class);
            put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
            put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
            put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        }};
    }
}
```

I'm not satisfied with my approach, whether it's because of a *hacky* way of bypassing static typing of `KafkaTemplate` by using `Object` as a value parameter or because of potential configuration inflexibility that might surface in future. Let's say I want to provide significantly differently configured templates for `FooResponse` and `BarResponse` messages. The difference would require different producer configs. Using a single template with a catch-all `Object` value type, it's not possible to achieve this.

Is there any way to provide more than one replying templates to the listener container to be chosen dynamically based on message value type? Does Spring Boot auto-configuration somehow attempt to address this kind of use case? I cannot use it in my project, but wouldn't mind any hints from its code. Perhaps this requirement can only be catered for by instantiating two separate listener containers (with different reply templates attached) listening on the same topic? If the latter approach is proper, how can I ensure correct messages delivery (ideally with exactly-once semantics) across multiple listener containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to provide more than one replying templates to the listener container to be chosen dynamically based on message value type?

No.

> Does Spring Boot auto-configuration somehow attempt to address this kind of use case?

No.

However, when the return type is `Message<?>`, the generic parameters are irrelevant. See

```java
    /**
     * Send a message with routing information in message headers. The message payload
     * may be converted before sending.
     * @param message the message to send.
     * @return a Future for the {@link SendResult}.
     * @see org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders#TOPIC
     * @see org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders#PARTITION
     * @see org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders#KEY
     */
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(Message<?> message);
```

The generic types are only meaningful when using the send methods that take a key and/or value.

You could create a subclass of `KafkaTemplate` and override the send methods to call a delegate template with the proper generic types, but that would be pointless unless you return `FooResponse` or `BarResponse` directly, instead of assembling them into a `Message<?>`.

Comment: I don't really get what's your advice. Should I just inject `KafkaTemplate<UUID, ?>`?

Comment: I am saying that you should not worry about it; the generic types are not relevant when you return `Message<?>`; you can inject whatever you want.

Comment: @Gary I do have a similar requirement  .Please check on my other question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657031/executionexceptiondue-to-org-springframework-kafka-requestreply-kafkareplytime/73663115?noredirect=1#comment130084814_73663115

Comment: Doesn't seem related to this question; this is just about generic parameters on the reply template. I will comment over there.