# ExecutionException:Due to: org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out using ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using kafka to publish both async and sync messages to the broker .One listener would listen to the topic and respond for both sync and async calls. **I am using same request topic for both the templates .**.
When using fire and forget(Async) I don't see any issues since listener would listen to the messages randomly from topic.When using synchronous call I am getting timeout exception.

1. Do I need to maintain multiple listeners for different templates ?
2. With same topic for both synchronous and async operations would there be any issues?

**KafkaConfig.java**

### //Template for synchornous call

```
@Bean 
public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Model, Model> replyingKafkaTemplate (
    ProducerFactory<String, Model> pf,
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Model> repliesContainer)
{
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Model, Model> replyTemplate =
        new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
    replyTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);
    return replyTemplate;
}

@Bean //register ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Model> repliesContainer (
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Model> containerFactory)
{
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Model> repliesContainer =
        containerFactory.createContainer("responseTopic");
    repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
    return repliesContainer;
}
```

### //Template for asynchronous call

```
@Bean

@Qualifier("kafkaTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, Model> kafkaTemplate (
    ProducerFactory<String, Model> pf,
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Model> factory)
{
    KafkaTemplate<String, Model> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
    return kafkaTemplate;
}
```

### Here is service class

```
@Service
public class KafkaService
{
    @Autowired
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Model, Model> replyingKafkaTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Model> kafkaTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaConfig config;
    public Object sendAndReceive (Model model)
    {

        ProducerRecord<String, Model> producerRecord =
            new ProducerRecord("requestTopic", model);
        producerRecord.headers()
            .add(
                new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "replyTopic"));
        RequestReplyFuture<String, Model, Model> replyFuture =
            replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord, Duration.ofSeconds(timeout));
        ConsumerRecord<String, Model> consumerRecord =
            replyFuture.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return consumerRecord.value();

    }
    public ResponseEntity<Object> send (final Model model)
    {

        final ProducerRecord<String, Model> producerRecord =
            new ProducerRecord("requestTopic", model);
        final ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Model>> future =
            kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
        final SendResult<String, Model> sendResult = future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sendResult, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

}
```

### Here is the listener class.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MessageListener
{
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "${group.id}", topics = "requestTopic", errorHandler = "customKafkaListenerErrorHandler",containerFactory = "customKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    @SendTo
    public Model consumer (Model model)
    {
        switch (model.getType()) {
        case "async":
            System.out.println("Async messages are retrieved");
        case "sync":
            System.out.println("Sync messages are retrieved");
            return model;
        }
        return model;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> customKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory)
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.
        setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
       concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()
       .setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
       concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.
       setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler());
       configurer.configure(concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
    return concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
}
```

### application.properties

spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

Debug Logs:

```
2022-09-15 15:48:07.771 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=com.sample.Model@37a32ae0, headers={kafka_offset=239, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59ff0b21, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=requestTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663282080306, kafka_groupId=consumer_group_new22}]]
2022-09-15 15:48:07.774 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [com.sample.Model@37a32ae0] - generating response message for it
2022-09-15 15:48:07.780 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : No replyTopic to handle the reply: com.sample.Model@37a32ae0
2022-09-15 15:50:54.760 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=com.sample.Model@3f766126, headers={kafka_offset=240, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59ff0b21, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=requestTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663282254296, kafka_groupId=consumer_group_new22}]]
2022-09-15 15:50:54.760 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [com.sample.Model@3f766126] - generating response message for it
2022-09-15 15:50:54.761 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : No replyTopic to handle the reply: com.sample.Model@3f766126
2022-09-15 15:51:44.482 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=com.sample.Model@56c68983, headers={kafka_offset=241, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59ff0b21, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=requestTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663282304204, kafka_groupId=consumer_group_new22}]]
2022-09-15 15:51:44.483 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [com.sample.Model@56c68983] - generating response message for it
2022-09-15 15:51:44.483 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : No replyTopic to handle the reply: com.sample.Model@56c68983
2022-09-15 15:52:03.237 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=com.sample.Model@6682bf3c, headers={kafka_offset=242, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59ff0b21, kafka_correlationId=[B@65f4dd3b, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=[B@79cca97, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=requestTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663282322947, kafka_groupId=consumer_group_new22}]]
2022-09-15 15:52:03.237 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [com.sample.Model@6682bf3c] - generating response message for it
2022-09-15 15:52:42.585 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=com.sample.Model@78a4382d, headers={kafka_offset=243, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59ff0b21, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=requestTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663282362320, kafka_groupId=consumer_group_new22}]]
2022-09-15 15:52:42.585 DEBUG 35380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [com.sample.Model@78a4382d] - generating response message for it
```

Comment: @Gary Russel, Can you please check on this?

Comment: You should show DEBUG logs (client and server side) for one of each type of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works exactly as I expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So73657031Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So73657031Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rkt(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.setReplyTemplate(template);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("so73657031-replies");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so73657031-replies");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so73657031").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so73657031-replies").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rTemplate,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        return args -> {
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future =
                    rTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("so73657031", 0, null, "test"),
                            Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            System.out.println(future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
            System.out.println(future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value());
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future2 = template.send("so73657031", "oneWay");
            System.out.println(future2.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {


    @KafkaListener(id = "so73657031", topics = "so73657031")
    @SendTo
    String listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

```
logging.level.root=warn
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter=debug
```

```
so73657031-0@2
2022-09-15 15:36:34.496 DEBUG 71184 --- [o73657031-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=test, headers={kafka_offset=2, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1582e8e4, kafka_correlationId=[B@2a266829, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_replyTopic=[B@3dad3e81, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=so73657031, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663270594381, kafka_groupId=so73657031}]]
test
2022-09-15 15:36:34.499 DEBUG 71184 --- [o73657031-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [TEST] - generating response message for it
TEST
so73657031-0@3
2022-09-15 15:36:34.519 DEBUG 71184 --- [o73657031-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=oneWay, headers={kafka_offset=3, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1582e8e4, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=so73657031, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1663270594514, kafka_groupId=so73657031}]]
oneWay
2022-09-15 15:36:34.519 DEBUG 71184 --- [o73657031-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Listener method returned result [ONEWAY] - generating response message for it
2022-09-15 15:36:34.519 DEBUG 71184 --- [o73657031-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : No replyTopic to handle the reply: ONEWAY
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for your quick demo .I could see you are using spring default container factory for listener.Though ReplyingTemplate extends KafkaTemplate would there be any issues if I use the my customListenerFactory?Basically how would the setReplytemplate differentiates two different templates(Producer ones).

Comment: I missed some code when copy/pasting my example; I set the `replyTemplate` in the `rkt` factory method. Edited. Use the bean name of the normal template when setting the container factory `replyTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks Gary . Would like to know how the acknowledgement works in this case .Since  from listener(consumer) side we have both sync and async calls being wrapped under one method , what value needs to be set to commit offset ? Is it Manual or Manual_Immediate ?I don't have batch of records ..

Comment: The reply container should not have any manual commit option; otherwise no offsets will be committed; the container will commit the replies offsets after each poll (by default), regardless of how many records the poll returns, or after each record if you set the `AckMode` to `RECORD`. Same thing with your consumer; no need for manual commits.

Comment: Thanks Gary .I have updated the listener factory bean properties along with the application.properties values. Please confirm if the configurations are good enough.

Comment: I don't really have time to check your work - is it still not working for you?

Comment: I added debug logs .I fired multiple async requests and at last one sync request .I noticed that if the async messages were still in processing state then listener is throwing timeout (In producer instance I could see the error) for sync call.Attaching the consumer log for your reference .Please check application properties and consumer factory configuration whenever you get time .Really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal, complete, example with steps to reproduce, that I can run myself,  I will take a look to see what you are doing wrong. It is too hard to speculate with just snippets and logs.

Comment: Sure Gary I will create a repo and share it with you in couple of days so that you can run from your end.Thanks